# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre del autor de un repositorio GIT?

Tags: git

Estoy haciendo un visor de repositorios git para web, para lo que necesito obtener el nombre del autor de repositorio.

Por autor me refiero a la persona que creó el repositorio.

He buscado y he encontrado este comando:

```
git show --format="%aN <%aE>"
```

Lo que me da como resultado:

```
Juan Pinz<C3><B3>n <user@mail.com>

diff --git a/README.md b/README.md
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..291468e
--- /dev/null
+++ b/README.md
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+# GitCli^M
+Simple git viewer
\ No newline at end of file
```

**¿Existe alguna forma de obtener solo el nombre del autor del repositorio?**

Comment: Y si obtienes el autor del primer commmit?

Comment: @ArieCwHat puede ser que uno cree el repositorio pero otra persona haga el primer commit.

Comment: @fedorqui y tambien podría ser que un repositorio sea un fork de otro... quien es el verdadero autor?.. primero el op debe definir bien a que se refiere con "autor" de un repositorio.

Comment: Tienes razón @ArieCwHat por autor me refiero a la persona que creó el repositorio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He revisado la documentación oficial y lo he logrado usando:

```
git show --format=format:"Autor: %an" --no-patch
```

Donde `--format` me permite definir el formato y la información del repositorio que quiero mostrar, en este caso uso `%an` que significa author name, y con `--no-patch` elimino la salida diff

Obteniendo como resultado:

```
Autor: Juan Pinz<C3><B3>n
```

**Fuente:** https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show

Comment: Pero este comando te daría solo el autor del _commit_ específico apuntado por _HEAD_, ya que se toma el _HEAD_ por defecto si no indicas ningún _commit_ o rama al ejecutar `git show`. No te da el autor del todo el repositorio.